# Can you create multiple FAT partitions with Boot Camp?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, boot-camp, fat32

Can you create multiple FAT partitions with Boot Camp?

We have a single partition but it is filling up with data and we want to create a second partition.  The first is the max size for FAT partitions.

Answer (score 2):

No. The Boot Camp Assistant will only let you create one FAT partition.

You can use Disk Utility to create another FAT partition, but it is not entirely obvious as to how to do it.

- Open Disk Utility from Applications/Utilities
- Select the hard drive you want to add the new FAT partition, then go to the "Partition" tab.
- Resize the partitions (or whatever else you must do) to create the space for your new FAT partition. Create a partition in this space, using the Mac OS Extended (Journaled) filesystem,  then click Apply.
- Once the new partition has been created, select it in the list in the left, go to the "Erase" tab, choose "MS-DOS (FAT)" as the format, and enter the name for your new FAT partition. Click Erase, then Erase again.

Comment: Well that worked but..  I couldn't boot into Windows (using Boot Camp).  Even when selecting Windows at startup the machine always booted into Leopard.  A couple times when attempting to boot into Windows I saw a quick glimpse of the blue screen..  and then it just went into Mac.  I deleted the new (second) FAT partition and the problem went away..  any ideas how to boot into Windows?

Comment: That is really odd… Try installing the rEFIt boot menu and see if you can boot into Windows using that. http://refit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Is it possible I need to update the XP boot.ini file?  Think I'll take a look at that..

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Boot Camp partition must be at the end of the drive. Therefore, if you want to create a FAT partition, it has to be between your HFS and NTFS partition.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does not need to be at the end. It is only that the Boot Camp manager does not let you create more than two partitions on a disk, hence why you have to do it manually with Disk Utility